# Translate ternary operator to if function

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to use if function inside the container to make the card is not showing when the data is null. However, it always give warning return an identifier.

I can make it using ternary operation, can someone help me to translate it into if function?

this is my code:

```
                        Container(
                            child: snapshot.data.notes == null
                                ? null
                                : Card(
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                          vertical: 0, horizontal: 8),
                                      child: Row(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Icon(Icons.short_text),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            width: 8,
                                          ),
                                          Expanded(
                                            child: NotesDetail(
                                              initialValue: snapshot.data.notes,
                                              changeValue: (value) {
                                                print(value);
                                              },
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                              )),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using a `function` instead.

```
Widget _buildCard(snapshot){
    if(snapshot?.data?.notes == null){
      return null;
    }else{
      return Card(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: 0, horizontal: 8),
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(Icons.short_text),
              SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: NotesDetail(
                  initialValue: snapshot.data.notes,
                  changeValue: (value) {
                    print(value);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

then call it in your container like this

```
Container(
  child: _buildCard(snapshot),
),
```

Comment: what ? after snapshot and data mean?

Comment: the `?` is to handle null so you don't run into `null` errors. You can remove it tho

Answer (score 0):

You can add not null condition at the top

```
if(snapshot.data.notes != null) 
                                 Card(
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                          vertical: 0, horizontal: 8),
                                      child: Row(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Icon(Icons.short_text),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            width: 8,
                                          ),
                                          Expanded(
                                            child: NotesDetail(
                                              initialValue: snapshot.data.notes,
                                              changeValue: (value) {
                                                print(value);
                                              },
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),

}
```